# How to give alias for a function in c

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

The problem is something like:

I have a function named `ADD_TWO(int,int);`, now in the program, I want to create its alias keeping the previous function untouched. Something like `ADD_TWO_NUMBERS(int,int);`. i.e if I call `ADD_TWO_NUMBERS` it should execute `ADD_TWO`.

I want to have an Alias for the function.

Comment: Why not create `ADD_TWO_NUMBERS` function, that will call `ADD_TWO`?

Comment: you can use a function pointer

Comment: `int (*ADD_TWO_NUMBERS)(int,int) = ADD_TWO;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int ADD_TWO(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    int (*ADD_TWO_NUMBERS)(int, int) = ADD_TWO;
    int result = ADD_TWO_NUMBERS(10, 12);  //or (*ADD_TWO_NUMBERS)(10, 12)
    cout<<"  Result :- "<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Use Function pointers

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using function pointers you can use [function-like macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros). Try something like

```
#define ADD_TWO_NUMBERS(x,y) ADD_TWO(x,y)
```

Comment: Function pointers are better since they can be given a scope.

Comment: Yeah. Nothing worse than a macro with bad breath.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag and assuming you're using a `c++11` compiler, then:

```
int ADD_TWO(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    auto ADD_TWO_NUMBERS = ADD_TWO;
    int result = ADD_TWO_NUMBERS(10, 12);
    cout << "  Result :- " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```